# Rails 3 no route matches (shallow routing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

This is my routes.rb

```
resources :subjects, :shallow => true do
   resources :skills, :only => [:new, :create]
end

resources :skills
```

This is my relevant controller (SkillsController)

```
def new
# if action is called by new_subject_skill_path then
# subject_id is not nil
   if params[:subject_id]
     @subject = Subject.find(params[:subject_id])
   end
   @skill = Skill.new
end
```

And this is the relevant view: (/views/subject/show.html.erb)

```
<%= link_to 'Add new skill', new_subject_skill_path %>
```

This is the result when I run **rake routes**

```
new_subject_skill GET  /subjects/:subject_id/skills/new(.:format) skills#new
```

Yet, when I try to render the view I get the following error

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"skills"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out - I forgot to add @subject to the link_to method.

```
<%= link_to 'Add new skill', new_subject_skill_path(@subject) %>
```